# How to add instances of sub types that have common base class to the same list in FSharp?

Tags: f#

I have a base abstract class named `Token`and some sub types like `NumToken`,`StrToken`.
I want to put their instances to the same list.

I can't declare a variable use `let l = list<'a when 'a :> Token>`

Then, I write

```
    let extractToken<'a when 'a :> Token>(lineNum:int, line:string) : 'a list option =
        let mutable result : 'a list = []
```

It works, but can not add element.`result <- new NumToken(lineNum, value) :: result` just say it needs `'a` but here is `NumToken`

Now I can use `new NumToken(lineNum, value) :> Token` and declare `Token list`.
It wokrs but looks ugly(I know fsharp doesn't do auto up cast..).

`list<_ :> Token>` doesn't work too, it only accepts one sub type.

Thx for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you model tokens using a class hierarchy and you create a list of tokens, the type of the list needs to be specific. You can either return `list<Token>` or `list<NumToken>`.

The flexible types with `when` constraints are useful only quite rarely - typically, when you have a function that takes some other function and returns whatever the other function produces, so I do not think you need them here. You can use `list<Token>` and write:

```
result <- (NumToken(lineNum, value) :> Token) :: result
```

That said, modelling token in F# using a class hierarchy is not very good idea. F# supports discriminated unions, which are much better fit for this kind of problem:

```
type Token = 
  | NumToken of int
  | StrToken of string
```

Then you can write a function that returns `list<Token>` just by writing

```
result <- (NumToken 42) :: result
```

Although, depending on what you are doing, it might be also a good idea to avoid the mutation.